# How does Facebook iPhone app implement the pop-over window for notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, user-interface

How does Facebook iPhone app (4.1) implement the pop-over window for notifications (see below for screenshot)?  I thought this was [only capable on the iPad](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html).  Is this a lookalike that they have custom built?

[image: Screenshot of Facebook 4.1 Popover Notifications]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this library which can implement pop over menus like facebook app: https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover

Answer (score 1):

I think it is far more complicated (and cleaner) than either of answers (guesses) so far. It is likely a completely separate view controller with it's own content view that is being added as a subview of the container view.

There are some libraries that so a similar thing, here is one for example:
https://github.com/KJoyner/SeaGlass/wiki/SGPopoverController-Documentation
http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=107632999326583
https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that the "popover" is just a subview within the mainview. 
First you create the subview, then hide it `mySubView.hidden = TRUE;` . When the user taps on the Globe button just "unhide" `mySubView.hidden = FALSE;` the subview with a nice 1 second animation (which will make it fade in).

Comment: Nice guess, but I highly doubt this is the case.. Are you saying that the app is loading all that notifications data and hiding in the hopes you click the globe to then unhide it... that would be a terrible waste of resources. And hiding/showing is a pretty bad design pattern except in the most simplest of cases - not a suitable solution for the notifications popover in the FB app.

Comment: Just a tip, use YES/NO rather then TRUE/FALSE - for consistency and not hurt your fellow Objective-C developers eyes

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the edges with the rounded corners, subtle inner glow, and outer shadow are part of a resizable 9 part image. From there, it just about placing it on screen stretching it out and drawing the arrow at the appropriate location to line up with the bar button item.

Comment: Important to point out this is a custom view to imitate a UIPopoverController, but the latter is exclusive for the iPad, using that on iPod Touch or iPhone results in an exception.